# GRANT FOR CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration, sql-grant

When I perform this command: CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mypassword' I get the error:

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]User does not have permission to perform this action.

Have any GRANT that I need take for this User?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CREATE MASTER KEY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174382.aspx)

> **Permissions**
>
> Requires CONTROL permission on the database.

Comment: How to give only for execute: CREATE MASTER KEY?